# How does Article deletion in batchmode works? Shopware 4

Tags: api, import, shopware

I found this in the Shopware 4 Rest Api Documentation, but this code doesn't work.

```
$restClient->delete(
        'articles/',
         array(
             array('id' => 2),
             array('id' => 4),
             array('id' => 6)
         )
);
```

Did anyone know, how it has to be?

Source:
http://community.shopware.com/Shopware-4-REST-API-verwenden_detail_989.html#Batch_Modus_.28Stapelverarbeitung.29

Comment: The syntax is correct. Maybe you use wrong data as id?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this example with my API client - it deleted the three items:

```
$response = $client->delete(
    'articles/',
    array(
        array('id' => 1),
        array('id' => 2),
        array('id' => 3),
    )
);
```

Be aware, that this was added in SW 4.2 IIRC - so you might not have it in older versions.